# Controller Method that accepts JSON, not working

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm having a hard time getting a complex JSON to be accepted by the server with HTTP PUT *(using Spring MVC)*.

I have two entities:

> **Building**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Building {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "building", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Floor> floors;

    // Default Constructor, Getters, Setters
}
```

> **Floor**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Floor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Building building;

    @Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
    private short number;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    // Default Constructor, Getters, Setters
}
```

> **Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin/Floors")
public class AdminFloorController {

    // Autowired Floor Service + Setter
    // Other methods

    @PutMapping(value = "/Save",
                consumes = "application/json",
                produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> save(@RequestBody Floor floor) {
        return floorService.save(floor) ?
                new ResponseEntity<String>("Floor was successfully saved.", HttpStatus.OK) :
                    new ResponseEntity<String>("Floor was not saved. An error may have occured.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

And here's the AJAX request. (From Form with ID 'main-form')

```
$("#main-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "Floors/Save",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "id": $("#main-form").find("input[name='id']").val(),
            "number": $("#main-form").find("input[name='number']").val(),
            "building": {
                "id": $("#main-form").find("select[name='building.id']").val()
            }
        }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#main-modal").modal("hide");
            createTable();
        }
    });
});
```

The AJAX request is properly constructed, along with the JSON object. *But when it sends*, the server always responds with an **Error 415: Unsupported Media Type.**

I explicitly told AJAX to send the request with a JSON body with the code:

> contentType: "application/json"

and the controller method is annotated with:

> @PutMapping(url, consumes = "application/json")

but it does not work. I have almost the same code in my Building REST Controller, and works like a charm. But I just can't seem to make it work with this entity.

**EDIT**

My issue was resolved. Turns out the problem was with Jackson's annotation, **@JsonManagedReference**. I simply removed said annotation but kept the Back Reference in the One side.

Comment: You explicitly say that your controller returns `text/html` (even though it doesn't). Drop all the explicit `produces`/`consumes` and let Spring do that automatically. (Also, it's a bad idea for a number of reasons to directly use your DAO classes for DTO, and this is the time to separate them. MapStruct can be your friend here.)

Comment: Do you want to send in json format and also do you want to receive in json format ?

Comment: @chrylis I dropped them. Still does not work. And what do you mean that it is a bad idea to directly use DAO inside DTO? I mean isn't that making the code loosely coupled? I'm gonna try and fix my code up by later morning PST. Ill have a look at MapStruct along the way. Thank you

Comment: @Sambit I want to send in JSON format. I think there are no problems with AJAX writing the JSON part.. the controller's the problem I think..

Comment: Before using Ajax call, did you check using any rest client like Postman ? If you are able to send and receive the response using any rest client, then there may be problem in your ajax call. First check in postman client and see what you are getting.

Comment: Loosely-coupled is a *good* thing.

Comment: @Sambit Postman isn't working as well... I made two more entities (ProductCategory and Product) which has a unidirectional relationship which Product class owns, and tried the same approach and it works.

Comment: @chrylis I removed the explicit call for consumes and produces, still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved. Turns out the problem was with Jackson's annotation, **@JsonManagedReference**. I simply removed said annotation but kept the Back Reference in the One side.